# Disqus Comentario , se superpone al footer

Tags: javascript, css, disqus

Tengo una sección de comentarios y debajo de ella tengo el footer , el problema es que sucede esto [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CSS

```
 /* COMMENTS DISQUS*/
          #disqus_thread{
               transform: translateY(19rem)translateX(-180px);
               width: 88rem;
               height: 80rem;


          }


  footer{
               transform: translateY(125rem);
               position: relative;
               width: 90rem;

          }
```

```
            <footer>
            <div class="img-F">
                <a href=""><img src="../src/instagram.png" alt="imagen de instagram"></a>
                <a href=""><img src="../src/discord.png"   alt="imagen de discord"></a>
                <a href=""><img src="../src/youtube.png"   alt="imagen de youtube"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="FT">
                <?php echo date ("Y") ?></div><p id="FT-P">texto</p> <p id="AlojaN">-texto</p>
            </footer>
```

alguna sugerencia de como resolver esto , he buscado en todos lados y en la comunidad Stack Ingles conseguí un post igual con el mismo problema y la solucion , pero de eso que vi no soluciono el problema, pensé que si ponía el footer en **position: relativa** iba a resolver pero no fue asi

Comment: Yo creo que se debe a los transforms que tienes,  por que no usar simplemente position absolute junto con position relative para ello?, de todas maneras e footer no deberia siempre encontrarse abajo?

Comment: eso se encuentra abajo , normalmente pero cuando escribo todos esos comentarios como en la foto de arriba , sucede eso , pero dejame probar eso de quitar los transform quizás sea eso y no se me ocurrió eso hasta ahora, uhm ya te digo si soluciono

Comment: pues no, lo soluciono

Comment: Hay alguna instrucción en el css que esta haciendo que tu footer se comporte así, ese no es ni de cerca el comportamiento normal de un footer, el footer esta encerrado en algún contenedor?

Comment: Ya actualize el código del footer ahi lo tienes completo,

Comment: Creo que en tu código original tienes un enclosed tag, (alguna etiqueta que te falta por cerrar o algo que no debias cerrar y cerraste), lo digo porque a mi me paso una vez una cosa super extrañisima con un overflow que hice y me pasaba que el overflow cogia unas partes pero no otras, hasta que revise varias vecez el código y dí con el problema, tenía 1 etiqueta sin cerrar de manera correcta y la otra nisiquiera tenia su pareja de cierre, verifica en el HTML que tengas todo correctamente cerrado y que no se te escapen caracteres del tipo <, > o / demas.

Comment: amigo revise todo , y la verdad no hay ningún tagname sin cerrar bien